# Problems installing python with pyenv in termux

Tags: pyenv, termux-linux

I referred to the instructions in the [pyenvwiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki) and tried to install the required packages, but some of them could not be found:

```bash
~ $ apt-get update; apt-get install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
Hit:1 https://mirrors.nju.edu.cn/termux/apt/termux-main stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://mirrors.nju.edu.cn/termux/apt/termux-root root InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libbz2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libbz2

Package libffi-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libffi

Package liblzma-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  liblzma

Package libxml2-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libxml2

E: Unable to locate package libssl-dev
E: Unable to locate package zlib1g-dev
E: Package 'libbz2-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libreadline-dev
E: Unable to locate package libsqlite3-dev
E: Unable to locate package libncursesw5-dev
E: Unable to locate package tk-dev
E: Package 'libxml2-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libxmlsec1-dev
E: Package 'libffi-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'liblzma-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Based on the above results, I used the following command as an alternative:

```bash
apt install make build-essential  zlib libbz2 libsqlite wget curl llvm ncurses* xz-utils tk libxml2 xmlsec libffi liblzma
```

After installing the above packages, I used `pyenv install 3.8.13` to install.

The following file is the result of the error report：

```bash
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/python-build.20220727123107.25556 ~
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/python-build.20220727123107.25556/Python-3.8.13 /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/python-build.20220727123107.25556 ~
checking build system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for python3.8... no
···
Python/bootstrap_hash.c:131:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'getrandom' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            n = getrandom(dest, n, flags);
                ^
Python/bootstrap_hash.c:135:17: error: implicit declaration of function 'getrandom' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            n = getrandom(dest, n, flags);
                ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [Makefile:1730: Python/bootstrap_hash.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Python/pytime.c:154:10: warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'double' changes value from 9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775808 [-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion]
    if (!_Py_InIntegralTypeRange(time_t, intpart)) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:228:82: note: expanded from macro '_Py_InIntegralTypeRange'
#define _Py_InIntegralTypeRange(type, v) (_Py_IntegralTypeMin(type) <= v && v <= _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type))
                                                                              ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:221:124: note: expanded from macro '_Py_IntegralTypeMax'
#define _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type) ((_Py_IntegralTypeSigned(type)) ? (((((type)1 << (sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1) : ~(type)0)
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
Python/pytime.c:207:14: warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'double' changes value from 9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775808 [-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion]
        if (!_Py_InIntegralTypeRange(time_t, intpart)) {
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:228:82: note: expanded from macro '_Py_InIntegralTypeRange'
#define _Py_InIntegralTypeRange(type, v) (_Py_IntegralTypeMin(type) <= v && v <= _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type))
                                                                              ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:221:124: note: expanded from macro '_Py_IntegralTypeMax'
#define _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type) ((_Py_IntegralTypeSigned(type)) ? (((((type)1 << (sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1) : ~(type)0)
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
Python/pytime.c:392:10: warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'double' changes value from 9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775808 [-Wimplicit-const-int-float-conversion]
    if (!_Py_InIntegralTypeRange(_PyTime_t, d)) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:228:82: note: expanded from macro '_Py_InIntegralTypeRange'
#define _Py_InIntegralTypeRange(type, v) (_Py_IntegralTypeMin(type) <= v && v <= _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type))
                                                                              ~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./Include/pymath.h:221:124: note: expanded from macro '_Py_IntegralTypeMax'
#define _Py_IntegralTypeMax(type) ((_Py_IntegralTypeSigned(type)) ? (((((type)1 << (sizeof(type)*CHAR_BIT - 2)) - 1) << 1) + 1) : ~(type)0)
                                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
3 warnings generated.
```

Comment: [`libbz2-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libbz2-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) should be available at least. Are you using Ubuntu (or an Ubuntu derivative)? Which version? Do you have the development sources enabled? Also, `termux` is a terminal software and seems irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: - About the version
I think the linux used in termux is supposed to be based on ubuntu, but different from it, here is the official explanation.[Differences from Linux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux) and [Package Management](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Package_Management)
- Regarding development sources: 
I'm not sure how development sources should be enabled, in termux the way to switch sources is via `terux-change-repo`, there doesn't seem to be a `development sources` repo as you mentioned

Comment: Oh, okay. Because there's also [this](https://termux.dev/), the same thing that particular tag is for.

Comment: I have doubts that this will work. [This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/comments/ffw39b/will_pyenv_work_in_termux_trying_to_run_as_python/) gives some reasons for that.

Answer (score 2):

In case people are searching for answers: follow https://gwangyi.github.io/posts/pyenv-in-termux-2/

But tldr:

1. Install pyenv first, ensure pyenv commands can be called
2. Copy/paste the final commands in the url above

I managed to installed it successfully but I faced some errors not mentioned in the post so I'll just put here:

spawn.h file not found: `pkg install libandroid-spawn`

ar not found: `pkg install binutils`

Both can be added into the pkg install command section to save time waiting for the errors to come up